# Is it possible to add mathematical symbols in x-axis values?

Tags: r, symbolic-math

Instead of adding mathematical symbols in x-labels, I'm trying to add $t_[1,n]$, $t_[2,n]$ and $t_[3,n]$ symbols at 0, 40 and 85 points in x-axis values, respectively. For doing so, my codes are

```
m=c(rnorm(40,0,.5),rnorm(45,5,.5));
plot(rep(1:85,1), m, type="l",  lty=1, xaxt='n', yaxt='n',ann=FALSE, col=4);
windowsFonts(script=windowsFont("Script MT Bold"));
title(xlab=c(expression(t[1,n]), expression(t[2,n]), expression(t[3,n])), family="script");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `axis` instead of `title`.

```
axis(side = 1, at = c(0, 40, 85), 
     labels = c(expression(t["1,n"]), 
                expression(t["2,n"]), 
                expression(t["3,n"])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try with `ggplot2`, like here:

```
library("ggplot2")

x <- 1:85
y <- c(rnorm(40,0,.5), rnorm(45,5,.5));

dane <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)

ggplot(dane, aes(x=x, y=y))+
    geom_line()+
    theme_bw()+
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1, 40, 85),
                     labels=c(expression(t[paste("[", 1, ",", n, "]")]),
                              expression(t[paste("[", 2, ",", n, "]")]),
                              expression(t[paste("[", 3, ",", n, "]")])))
```

Comment: Thanks! But I prefer to use that without any packages. +1 for such nice answer!